# Filemaker - Can I use a portal like a drop-down value list?

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to work around a limitation that Filemaker 12 seems to have. In a value list that links to an ODBC attached SQL Server database, it doesn't display every piece of data. If there are 2 people with the same last name for example, it only displays the first person with that last name in the list. This is verified by the following in the Filemaker documentation (which I found after a lot of digging)

> If the value list is defined to display information from two fields, items will not be duplicated for the field on which the value list is sorted. For example, if the value list displays information from the Company field and the Name field, and if the values are sorted by the Company field, only one person from each company will appear in the value list.

Portals on the other hand will find all the related data, I just don't understand how do something with the data once I get it in the portal. I essentially thus wish to use a portal AS my drop-down value list, and then to use it as I would have a value list (which is then to act as the key to do the rest of the lookups on the page to fill out the invoice.

The major issue here (other than this maddening choice Filemaker seems to make) is that the external file I am pulling the data from is an ODBC mounted SQL Server file, so I can't do something easy like a calculated field which would give me last name & " " & first  which would make almost every person unique. Filemaker won't let me do that because it says I can't do that with a field that is not indexed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we're starting with table `MyTable` and we're trying to get a ID from the `People` table for the selected person, which we'll call `ID` so that we can put it into `MyTable::PersonID`

Start by creating a new Table Occurrence of your `People` table and call it `PeopleWhoCanBeSelected`. If you want every person in the People table you can connect it to MyTable with the `X` relationship. If you want to show just a subset of the people you can build a different relationship.

Now, on a layout displaying records from `MyTable` you will make a portal showing records from the `PeopleWhoCanBeSelected` table.

In the portal put a button. When that button is pressed use the Set Field script step:

```
Set Field MyTable::PersonID to:
    PeopleWhoCanBeSelected::ID
```

That should do it. You can make the button an invisible overlay on the entire portal record if you like, so that the user clicks on "the name" instead of "the button next to the name".

Now, if you want to pull additional data through to the MyTable record, you'll need to create a second Table Occurrence, called `People` with the relationship `MyTable::PersonID = People::ID`. Then you can get information on the specifically chosen person through that relationship.

Comment: One thing to think about - you could use a local global to act as a filter to the portal. With some triggering you could create filtering effect rather than a huge portal - which may improve your performance.